# Laravel - install in subfolder of document root

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I have a static homepage at `http://example.com`, and now I want to set up a Laravel app in `public_html/project` directory.

That makes the public URL to access the project: `http://example.com/project/public`

I don't want to have that `public segment` at the end, what should I do?

Comment: Depends on what web server you are using.

Comment: It's apache, but changing documentroot only applies to the top most level isn't it?

Comment: this might help: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host